# Is "I typed out the text" the same as "typed up the text"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, phrase-usage, phrase-choice

According to Cambridge Dictionary, "type out" and "type up" are the same

> [type something out/up](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/type-out-up?q=type%20sth%20out) phrasal verb with type verb [ I or T ]
>
> to make a typed copy of a piece of text that is written by hand: Could
> you type up the minutes from the meeting, please?

But from other sources, it seems "**type up**" means to create a final version of something that has been partially written and "**type out**" means you just type whatever words on a paper or from a source (maybe word for word).

**Is "I typed out the text" the same as "typed up the text"?**

Answer (score 1):

To "type up" means to *create a document* by typing.

To "type out", like you say, means to type a bunch of words.

The object of "type up" is the document created, and the object of "type out" is the words.

So while both "I typed **up** the text" and "I typed **out** the text" are natural sentences, the meaning of "the text" in each is different.

Merriam-Webster has these two definitions:

> **text** *noun*
> **1 a (1) :** the original words and form of a written or printed work
> **b :** a work containing such text

In the first sentence, "the text" has meaning **1 b**, while in the second "the text" has meaning **1 a (1)**.

Comment: I see a similarity with 'write up' and 'write out'.

Comment: "[Up](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/up)" has meanings of transforming into a better or more developed state, while "out" refers to producing the output of a mechanical process.